# A single relationship type must be specified for CREATE in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a relationship between two nodes using using the below query:

```
load csv with headers from 
"file:C:/Users/abc/Documents/Neo4j/RT__RISK_LOSSEVENT.csv" as risklossevent 
match (a: RT__RISK_LOSSEVENT {LossEventId: risklossevent.LOSSEVENT_ID}),
(b: RT_RISK {RiskId: risklossevent.RISK_ID}) 
create (a)-[ASSOCIATED_WITH]->(b);
```

It is throwing the an error stating

```
A single relationship type must be specified for CREATE (line 1, column 236 (offset: 235))

Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax
```

For creating the two nodes, I have used the below queries:

```
load csv with headers from 
file:C:/Users/abc/Documents/Neo4j/RT__RISK_LOSSEVENT.csv" as risklossevent
create (rle1:RT__RISK_LOSSEVENT {RiskId: risklossevent.RISK_ID, LossEventId: risklossevent.LOSSEVENT_ID});

load csv with headers from "file:C:/Users/abc/Documents/Neo4j/RT_RISK.csv" as risk 
create (rle3:RT_RISK {RiskId: risk.RISK_ID, Owner: risk.OWNER, RiskCategory: risk.RISK_CATEGORY, Description: risk.DESCRIPTION});
```

Anyone knows what wrong with the syntax or the query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed the exception you get is not really concerning the syntax error you have and thus not meaningful.

You forgot to add a `colon` : `:` before the relationship type in your query :

```
create (a)-[:ASSOCIATED_WITH]->(b);
```

Comment: NB: I have created an issue on the neo4j repository : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6568